# Indirect lighting makes all objects looks like silver

Tags: lighting, color

I was following this tutorial [Create a Modern Bedroom in Blender in 35 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUf9VltV4Cc).
And all was going great until at some point he did something behind scenes and his looks good and mine looks like in the picture below. 
No matter what color I put on my shader for pillows, curtains or other objects, it still shows up as silverish. 
The first picture is my render and the second picture is how it is supposed to look.

Can anyone direct me to where the issue would be? I played with all settings I knew in Blender and can't figure this out. Is this a lighting or shader, or HDRI problem?
Even a wild guess will help.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: While i can't be sure, since you cut out the part that would show it, but are you maybe in "Material Preview" mode instead of "Rendered"?

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry i didnt mean to cut the options off, I am in Rendered mode here though. I noticed the difference between my scene and the one in the tutorial happens around min 20, if you see before he adds the chair, the scene looks similar to mine but after he adds the chair materials, his scene materials change completely and I don't know what he did because he didn't show it.

Comment: Hi :). In 21:22 he says "when you bake your indirect lighting that is too blue".. So that's probably what he did off-screen.

Comment: He did use a RGB curve on multiple color channels to adjust away from the strong blue tint and then freed the lighting cache. Both seem to be needed to get to the result, so maybe you missed one of those settings.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I also did tinker with the curves but still my result only looks closer to his if I turn my render to Cycles, whereas his looks like that in Eevee. I asked someone to try to do the tutorial and he had the same issue around there. It's something weird the more blue you take out the more blue you have in the scene. 
So I found a solution to match his scene when I rotated my hdr and reduced its strength by 50%, now it looks much better.
Again, thanks! :)